# Get all rows of NOT value WITHOUT subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

Let's say that I have a table like this

```
Id    item_id   type_id       date
1     1         1             2016-08-11
2     2         2             2016-08-12
3     2         3             2016-08-13
4     3         4             2016-08-14
5     4         3             2016-08-15
6     2         3             2016-08-16
```

As you can see, I have item with id 2 that has 2 types (type_id 2 and 3). How do I get all items (item_id) that are NOT of type 3 WITHOUT using subqueries. For example the expected result should be:

```
Id    item_id   type_id       date
1     1         1             2016-08-11
4     3         4             2016-08-14
```

If I write the following SQL statement:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE type_id <> 3 GROUP BY item_id;
```

The above statement returns also type 2 (because it has a row in the table that is ALSO not of type 3).

Any help please.

Comment: With that table data, what's the expected result?

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? "all items that are NOT of type 3" - in this case, you don't need the GROUP BY clause, do you? What am I missing?

Comment: It's easy to see what he wants to do.. the only problem is getting it without a subquery if he wants all fields and not just the item_id

Comment: I corrected the expected result @HoneyBadger

Comment: I do group by because I don't want to have two results for the same item_id @EatPeanutButter

Comment: maybe I am the one missing something.  It looks and from your narrative sounds like you want to remove any item_id that is related to type_id = 3 in any row.  It doesn't appear that you are doing any further aggregation past that.  Or after that are you only wanting 1 row per item_id and if so how are you identifying which type_id and date?

Comment: Is it possible to have more than two types? And what is the reason to avoid subqueries since I'm curious to know.

Comment: Yes it is possible to have more than two types. I just don't like subqueries (for performance reasons)

Comment: using EXISTS instead of a self join can actually yield better performance some times.  Just because there is a subselect or nested select doesn't mean performance will be terrible.  Withouth knowing indexs and a lot more it is impossible for people to determine what is best performance for you.  Using a self join works, I have updated my answer accordingly

Comment: Subqueries might hinder performance when you write them but not when I do.  Avoiding subqueries when they are appropriate to the task at hand increases development time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can count the number of times an item_id has a type_id of 3 and only select those with a count of 0

```
SELECT  `Id`, `item_id`, `type_id`, `date`
FROM    MyTable
GROUP BY item_id
HAVING  COUNT(CASE WHEN type_id = 3 THEN 1
              END) = 0
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49e1d/1)

just be aware that if you have more than one record for each item_id, that grouping by item_id will only give you one of the records in your result.

Comment: I do want 1 record per item_id. That's why I do the GROUP BY item_id. Your answer seems to work. I just don't understand the CASE part...

Comment: The problem is going to be that you'll only get one row per group even though you can have more than one item of type <> 3 per group.

Comment: It's ok to have one row per group of item_id (that's what I need).

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DISTINCT t1.*
FROM
     my_table t1
     LEFT JOIN my_table t2
     ON t1.item_id = t2.item_id
     AND t2.type_id = 3
WHERE
     t2.id IS NULL
```

If item_id to type_id combination never repeats you don't need DISTINCT

SQL fiddle proving it works http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c49e1d/4/0

Comment: I said NO SUB QUERIES

Comment: I doubt that this is impossible

Comment: Okay so I had a duh moment :) I usually like the self-joins to so may people answer with IN and Exists on this site it has changed my thinking some...

Comment: Would your answer cause problems if I had to join my_table with the tables where item_id and type_id are coming from?

Comment: you'll get more than one record for each item_id that has more than one type_id.. not sure how distinct helps here either

Comment: @JamieD77 you will get more than 1 record but because only columns from first instance of the table is returned then you will only get 1 record per record in table 1 that meets that criteria, therefore distinct works. check out the sql fiddle link

Comment: @user765368 yes the method will work but it will be a little more difficult to ensure you have the logic down.  if you post a structure/example with the 2-3 tables involved I will be glad to help you figure it out.

Comment: @JaydipJ yes equal to 3 because I am using a left join to eliminate the records that match that criteria

Comment: I tried your answer locally in my database, it returns multiple rows for some item_ids. I added GROUP BY item_id and got rid of the DISTINCT, it works. The GROUP BY item_id is important in my case.

Comment: @Matt  your join might duplicate records, but you're excluding those duplicates by saying `WHERE t2.id IS NULL`, that's the only reason i say `DISTINCT t1.*` is not necessary

Comment: @JamieD77 that is correct there would be more than 1 record for item_id if there is more than 1 type_id but never a item_id that is related to type_id = 3 in any row.  That is what the OP question was and up held by his comments

Comment: @Matt except for all of his comments that said he only wants one record per item_id.. :)

Comment: @JamieD77 yes his comment to you was he wanted one item_id but I had asked questions and his comment to shawnt00, and his desired output seemed to suggest he wanted the records to item_ids that matched his criteria.  Let's just say that I have asked for that clarification and there is some fuzziness there which.  I like your answer if just wanting the aggregation not the whole records. And you are actually correct I do eliminate the duplicates with the where clause so I can remove the distinct.

Comment: @JamieD77 unless the data set would repeat item_id to type_id on more than 1 row then the DISTINCT would be necessary again

Comment: @Matt assuming the date field matches.. and the primary key `ID` certainly would be different

Comment: Sorry but I'm accepting JamieD77's answer. I like that answer better.

Comment: By all means accept the answer that works for you and if you truly just need item_id not the entire results or all combination of that item_id to type_id then his answer is definitely the way to go, I was providing the way to get entire rows of information not simply an aggregated column because that is what your OP seemed to suggest you wanted.

Comment: Your answer is helpful too but sorry I didn't precise in the question that I wanted only one row per item_id @Matt